# Alarm Manager not getting called with Google Nexus 4

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I have developed one **Android** app. I need to set Alarms for certain operations.

The problem is that the Alarm receiver works fine with all other devices but **with Google Nexus 4 it sometimes getting called sometime not!** :-(

When I set alarm it prints the log as below which is 5 minutes later than current time.

```
Alarm set for : Fri Jun 20 06:07:00 GMT+00:00 2014
```

But when the time arrives it sometimes get called sometime not! :-(

**I have put log inside the receiver**, it prints it sometime.

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API19, alarm manager is bit random:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thanks! I want to set repeating alarm with interval of 1 day. I have seen the API and there is no way to set it... I meant there is no method like setExactAlarm method :-( Please help!

Comment: @SanketShah Please, read my answer again. As a side note, if your app will support older devices too, you should check device API level before setting the alarm.

Comment: Thanks for your help... now I am checking the API level before setting the alarm and set it accordingly as you said...